# How can i controll errors, mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

this is about a private match, game has 2 players, name and password, if you want to join u must match them.

Question is: How can i controll when match or name dont match  or the game is already full so i can send different messages to the client side ?
I would be so pleased if anyone can show me another helpfull post or some link to documentation can help me.

Thank you

```
exports.joinPrivateMatch = (req, res) =>{
let gamePass = req.body.password;
let gameName = req.body.name;
let playerid = req.body.playerid;
let socketPID = req.body.socketid;

creatematch.findOneAndUpdate({player2: null, name: gameName, password: gamePass}, {
    player2: playerid,
    socketID2: socketPID
}, {new:true}, function(err, result){
    if(result){
        res.send(result);
        ioConnection.to(`${result.socketID1}`).emit('addplayer2', result);
        ioConnection.to(`${result.socketID1}`).emit('matchfull', /*{ScreenReady: true} */);
        ioConnection.to(`${result.socketID2}`).emit('matchfull', /*{ScreenReady: false} */);
    }
    if(err){
        return res.send('something went wrong', err)
    }
    else{
        console.log('Contraseña incorrecta o partida llena')
        ioConnection.to(`${socketPID}`).emit('sadsmiley')
    }
})
```

i wrote something like this:

```
 if(name != gameName || password != gamePass){
console.log("name or password doesnt match")
ioConnection.to(`${socketPID}`).emit('findError1')
}
```

But as long as i dont get response, name and password will be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Express middle-ware in this purpose...
See [Using Express Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

```
var app = express()
var router = express.Router()

// a middleware function with no mount path. This code is executed for every request to the router
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  //here implement code for matching gameName & Password
  //if not match, return authentication error response
  //else pass the control to the next function 
  next()
})
```